# Filtering by 2 keywords in python

Tags: python, twitter, filter, tweepy

So I have been stuck for a while I'm using tweepy in python and I am trying to filter tweets by the words "like" AND "retweet" or "RT"

The problem is I have no clue how to filter by two words. This is the code I have right now successfully filtering by one word but I want to filter by 2 at the same time.

```
tweets_listener = MyStreamListener(api)    
stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweets_listener)    
stream.filter(track=["giveaway"], languages=["en"])
```

Comment: according to the [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html#step-3-starting-a-stream), `track` is an array (list) of search terms to stream. So in your function, use `track=["like","retweet","RT"]`. Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

From [Twitter's documentation on the `track` standard stream parameter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters):

> A comma-separated list of phrases which will be used to determine what
>   Tweets will be delivered on the stream. A phrase may be one or more
>   terms separated by spaces, and a phrase will match if all of the terms
>   in the phrase are present in the Tweet, regardless of order and
>   ignoring case. By this model, you can think of commas as logical ORs,
>   while spaces are equivalent to logical ANDs (e.g. ‘the twitter’ is the
>   AND twitter, and ‘the,twitter’ is the OR twitter).

Tweepy does the comma separation for you, so if `"like" AND ("retweet" OR "RT")` is what you want, you can expand that to `("like" AND "retweet") OR ("like" AND "RT")` and do `stream.filter(track=["like retweet", "like RT"], languages=["en"])`. Otherwise, if you want `("like" AND "retweet") OR "RT"`, you can simply do `stream.filter(track=["like retweet", "RT"], languages=["en"])`.

Comment: Thanks that worked! But I added another thing to my code and it broke again :(.